# Does SQL Server Compact needs to be supported by hoster's server prior to use it in web project?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am going to use SQL Server Compact for one small website. Just to store articles for my site. Does my hoster's server need to support SQL Server Compact in order to use it on my project?

Comment: No. If they support .Net all you do is include the binaries for SQL Compact in your project.

Comment: Medium trust or full trust is required